# Extracting p tags from a div - Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, css-selectors

I wish to extract category and title from the following HTML piece of code using Scrapy:

```
<div class="box-text box-text-products">
  <div class="title-wrapper">       
     <p class="category uppercase is-smaller no-text-overflow product-cat op-7">Supplements     </p>
     <p class="name product-title"><a href="https://martslu.com/product/explosive-energy-pre-workout-cherry-punch-300g/">Explosive Energy Pre Workout Cherry Punch – 300g</a></p></div><div class="price-wrapper">
</div>      
</div>
```

The following is the code I wrote

```
    def parse(self,response):
        for product in response.css('div.box-text.box-text-products::text'):
            yield{
                'category': product.css('div.title-wrapper.p::text').get(),
                'title': product.css('div.title-wrapper>p.name product-title::text').get()}
```

I am still unclear as to how to point out specific class names in p tags. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Not enough info provided, `div.box-text` doesn't exist in the html you given.

Comment: Updated, please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
def parse(self,response):
    for product in response.css('div.box-text.box-text-products'):
        yield {
            'category': product.css('div.title-wrapper > p.category::text').get(),
            'title': product.css('div.title-wrapper > p.product-title > a::text').get()
        }
```

You're not familiar with CSS Selectors. Google some material and learn the syntax.

Parsing in `scrapy` depends on `parsel`, which has introduced 2 additional custom non-standard pseudo-elements

- `::text`
- `::attr(name)`

Besides these 2 custom pseudo-elements, most of the css selector syntax are supported.

Comment: Thank you so much i realised the stupid mistake I made in the css selector for response.css()